# Cannot Access Data Retrieved from Observable [Angular 2, Typescript]

Tags: angular, http, typescript, rxjs

I'm getting a promise error whenever I reference a variable that is fed data from an observable. Example.

I have my class Stat defined in the component:

```
export class Stats {
  name: string;
  percentage: number;
  constructor(n: string, p: number) {
    this.name = n;
    this.percentage = p;
  }
}
```

Now this is where its getting messy, I want data over from Http to populate my array so I'm doing this

```
export class StatsComponent {

  public stat1: Stats[] = [];

  constructor(private _httpService: HttpService, private _http: Http) {
     this._httpService.getParams("myURL").subscribe(S => {
       this.stat1 = S;
    });
  }
```

getParams() fetches data for me with an observable like so

```
getParams(url: string): Observable<Stats[]>{
return this._http.get(url)
       .map(res =><Stats[]>res.json());
    }
```

In stat.component.ts, I have this array that I want the data to populate it. Sorry stat2 doesn't exist, its just a concept on how I want to populate the data so I'm assuming I'll declare stat2[] in the same way I declare stat1[]

```
  public lineChartData: Array<any> = [
    { data: [this.stat1[0].data, this.stat2[0].data], label: 'Data 1' },
    { data: [this.stat1[1].data, this.stat2[1].data], label: 'Data 2' },
    { data: [this.stat1[2].data, this.stat2[2].data], label: 'Data 3' }
  ];
```

Whenever I reference any of my local variable that received data from the observable in the constructor, they throw a Promise Error. How can I use data outside the scope of my .subscribe (in the constructor).

Comment: Where is stat2 coming from?

Comment: it doesn't, but I hope to do so in the same way as stat1

Answer (score 0):

You can move the assignment within the subscribe like this:

```
  lineChartData: Array<any>;

  constructor(private _httpService: HttpService, private _http: Http) {
     this._httpService.getParams("myURL").subscribe(S => {
       this.stat1 = S;
       this.lineChartData = [
          { data: [this.stat1[0].data, this.stat2[0].data], label: 'Data 1' },
          { data: [this.stat1[1].data, this.stat2[1].data], label: 'Data 2' },
          { data: [this.stat1[2].data, this.stat2[2].data], label: 'Data 3' }
       ];
    });
```

A few things:

1) It is highly recommended that async operations (such as getting data) are **NOT** in the constructor. Consider instead using the ngOnInit method.

2) I'm not sure where stat2 is coming from ... so not sure this will work as is.

Comment: regarding 2) it doesn't. I just added it as a concept

Comment: Based on the concept, does the above make sense to you?

Comment: after testing it out, I'm getting a promise error like so: http://i.imgur.com/qg1B1w4.jpg but it seems to be related to ng2-charts that I imported